# Playing audio with pound sign in the source doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mp3, html5-audio

I'm trying to play audio files with a pound sign in the source, but JavaScript gives me this error when I try to play them with a `new Audio()` object.

> NotSupportedError: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable.

Here's the function that creates the Audio object and plays it. I outputted the parameter `note` to the console to make sure the right path was being specified and it wasn't just a file note found error (pun intended). I tried replacing the `#` in the parameter `note` with `\#`, but that didn't do anything (didn't think it would, but was worth trying before asking for help).

The other files used are on [GitHub](https://github.com/MiiLikesYoshi/PianoDream) if you need to view them.

```js
/*
 * Author:  Adam Oates
 * Created: 2/7/2019
 * Filename: main.js
 *
 */

function playNote(note) {
 let audio = new Audio();
 audio.src = "res/tones/" + note + ".mp3";
 console.log("res/tones/" + note + ".mp3");
 audio.play();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 
 let pdo = new PianoDream();
 
 // plan to have different piano layouts in the future
 $("main").load("res/layouts/defaultLayout.html", function() {
  $("div.key").on("click", function() {
   console.log($(this).text());
   playNote($(this).text());
  });
 });
 
});
```

Comment: Lol, wrong pound sign. This # is also called a pound sign. [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign)

Comment: Full path should look like `res/tones/A#0.mp3` which it does, but I get the error mentioned above when the source has the pound sign in it.

Comment: You'll need to URL encode the # character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else wondering: As pointed out by Alohci, I had to URL encode the characters. The pound sign then becomes `%23` in a URL. JavaScript actually has a function called `encodeURIComponent()` that encodes the characters for you.

You can view a list or URL encoded characters here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp